# Scheme Solving CCZ4 Formalism Numerically

Tags: numerics

For my thesis, I have to implement the [CCZ4 formalism](https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2254) into an existing code (I tried to type the evolution equations here but does not seem to work).

However, I can't seem to come up with a scheme to solve these equations. For instance, [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.05723), the authors give an explicit scheme on how to solve the ADM equations (see page eight). I am looking for something similar. I tried something similar but that did not get me far. Furthermore, I am aware of the codes such as  `GRChombo` (see [here](https://www.grchombo.org/)) that are able to solve these equations but I can't find anywhere in what order they solve these equations. I tried looking at the source code of `GRChombo` but I could not anything useful that would solve my problem (I am not familiar with `C++`)

Hence, I am looking for references or ideas on how I could solve my problem.

Thanks in advance!